# 3 variable systems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1)   $x+y-z = 6$

2)   $x+3y-2z = 14$

3)   $3x - 2y + z = -5$

I multiply 1 by -1 and add to 2, I multiply 2 by -3 and add to 3. I do not get anyone close to a proper answer.

Comment: This gives you a new smaller system $2y-z=8$ and $-11y+7z=-47$. Solve this for $y$ and $z$ as usual by substitution as you mentioned you were familiar with, and then $x$ follows by plugging those values for $y$ and $z$ back in.

Comment: I did and I got y=33.6 which I know is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, you have $2y-z=8$ implies $z=2y-8$, and so $-11y+7(2y-8)=-47$, that is, $3y-56=-47$, or $3y=9$, which implies $y=3$, not $33.6$. Now you can plug back into $z=2y-8$ to find $z$, and $x$ should be easily calculable as well.

Comment: I don't see how you got that answer, I am really bad at math. I get 3y=101

Comment: @Adam don't swear and despair... *Add* $56$ to both sides of $3y - 56 = -47$, so $3y = - 47 + 56 = 9$.

Comment: I am just incredibly bad at math, I have done this problem 6 times or so and couldn't get the correct ansnwer. This is why I fail every single test I take, I just can't do simple math for some reason. I am quite good at adding in my head and everything, calculating the tip in my head or anything you will come by in a day to day situation but when I do classroom math I always mess it up.

Comment: @Adam: So you've got the basic skills. Try to keep your cool in the classroom and don't *think* you're bad at math.

Comment: I have a calm mind I just can't manage to do any of these problems, I either mess up the method, forget the memorization things or mess up simple math. I am a very calm person and these things don't make me nervous I just can't do it for some reason.

Comment: @Adam: Well, I don't know you, so I really can't say anything more. But one thing I'm sure of is that you should stop convincing yourself of your inability to *do it*. (@yunone: sorry about the pings)

Comment: I am just very bad at math I guess, I don't know what to do with my life. I think people told me to be a welder because they think I am too stupid to do math. I just don't get it, people say math just takes practice but they are the lucky ones woh are good at math, I put in way more practice hours than them.

Comment: Maybe if you post how you got $y=33.6$, someone here could point out where you went wrong, and help you fix that particular misunderstanding.

Comment: @yunone: I guess it's $101/3 \approx 33.6$ and $101 = 47 + 56$.

Comment: I added 56 and 47 instead of subtracting.

Comment: Oh whoops, then it was already addressed. My mistake.